# Firebase equivalent of MySQL's NOW()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to create new records with current timestamp (+ one hour)? And is it possible to select only the records with greater timestamp than now?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in operator for the server-side timestamp in queries. You'll have to build something using the client-side timestamp and the [known latency to the server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#clock-skew) or read a [server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps) first.

Comment: Can we use Cloud Functions and database-events.Will there be any noticeable delay.Which is the best approach? @frank-van-puffelen

Answer (score 1):

You can use client time in firebase.

OR

Use Cloud Functions for Firebase that lets you run mobile backend code that automatically responds to events triggered by Firebase features in your case the 
databas-events

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Eg: Listens for /records/{pushId}/time and write time in /records/{pushId}/servertime

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/records/{pushId}/time')
    .onWrite(event => {

      var date = new Date();
      var current_hour = date.getHours();
 return event.data.ref.parent.child('servertime').set(current_hour);
}
```

Also See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7E13ZBCyKT0